# StackView implementation in Android 2.X

Tags: android, android-widget

Need to implement a `View` which contains 5 Images placed in stack order. When user move finger up or down at this `View` picture replace each other.

This approach looks like `StackView` in Android 3.0, but standard `StackView` displays applications and it works from API 11 level and I develop for Eclair.

Would like to know if you know some sources where this kind of view has already implemented for Android 2.X, or may be you'll give me an advice to try another one approach to implement this stylization kind.

Comment: you may use GridView and make it even available for 1.6

Comment: Don't understand you completely. You suggest me to use one-dimensional scrollable view and I need to scroll my view's content in both X and Y axis

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to pull the StackView source from a recent Android source base and place it in your application. If I were to do this I would certainly change the package name, and in order to maintain forward compatibility I would see if the original class exists on the platform and use that instead.

If I were to implement what you describe without consideration for having StackView, I would think this could be done easily enough by overriding ImageView and giving my class an array of images to have the source cycle through.

Comment: Approach of overriding `ImageView` allows to display only one image at time and I need to display foreground image and also pieces of background images in stack.

Comment: Did you achieve what you wanted? I faced the same issue, if you have some ideas of how to implement stack view can you share with me?